# Как в vue-router открыть ссылку в новой вкладке?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Как в [vue](/questions/tagged/vue) приложение при использовании [vue-router](/questions/tagged/vue-router) открыть ссылку в новой вкладке?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40015037/5610621

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `vue-route` начиная с версии **3.0.1** для `route-link` нужно использовать параметр `target` со значение `_blank`, пример:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'routeName'}" target="_blank">Link Text</router-link>
```

если же, данный способ не подходит, то тогда можно это сделать в необходимом нам обработчике события:

```
let route = this.$router.resolve({name: 'routeName', params: {}}});
window.open(route.href, '_blank');
```

Answer (score 0):

В URL вы должны написать так:
'URL?**_target=blank**'